# WP_Query last five posts, simply ordered by meta_value

Tags: wp-query, query-posts, meta-query

I can't believe I'm asking this question. It feels like such a simple method, yet I've poured over the WP pages and dozens of similar questions to no avail, so here it is...

I've got a WP_Query with the following, that just gets the last 5 posts:

```
$args = Array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => '5'
)
```

All I wanted to do was order the last 5 posts by the meta_value_num of the meta_key 'views'. But instead, when I put in something like the following, it grabs the top five most viewed posts ever.

```
$args = Array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => '5',
  'meta_key' => 'views',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num'
)
```

What am I doing wrong? I feel like this is endlessly frustrating, probably more so because I know the solution is almost certainly simple as pie.

Comment: Try 'order' = 'desc'. Actually you'd have to use 'orderby' = 'date' and 'order' = 'desc', but you need ordering by meta key and unfortunately you cannot use 2 orderby values! Or try the date orderby with a meta query.

Answer (score 2):

**You need to sort in descending order** so the last 5 posts will be on top. Just add `'order' => 'DESC'` to your args.

```
$args = Array(
  'post_type' => 'post',
  'posts_per_page' => '5',
  'meta_key' => 'views',
  'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
  'order' => 'DESC'
);
```